# Error while running an example code :Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Tags: python-3.x

When i try to run a basic addition code, i get the following error

i used below line to install tensorflow

```
C:\Users\bjnag> pip install tensorflow --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

Im using Windows10, Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bjnag\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\bjnag\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\bjnag\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\bjnag\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\bjnag\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/bjnag/Desktop/Machine Learning/Linked in/tensorflow/Exercise Files/02/addition final.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\bjnag\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\bjnag\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\bjnag\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\bjnag\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\bjnag\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\bjnag\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\bjnag\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bjnag\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\bjnag\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\bjnag\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\bjnag\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\bjnag\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error here on Windows 10 while trying to run tf==v2.1. After I carefully check all the system version requirements from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements) and read [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18503) page, what really solved for me was updating the Visual C++ redistributable.